# json_decode file_get_contents problem

Tags: php, file-get-contents, json

Ok the following php code is working fine

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://tiny.cc/example22');

$obj = json_decode($json);
$example = $obj->{'screen_name'};
?>

User: <?php echo $example; ?>
```

It shows the screen name 'muffinlosers' just like i wanted

But if i change 'screen_name' to 'total_coins', why it doesn't show the total coins?

I need help with this, i want just to show the total coins

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$obj->experience->total_coins;
```

Also, this

> $example = $obj->{'screen_name'};

Should simply be

```
$example = $obj->screen_name;
```

Comment: @Alexis You don't need to type the same comment for every answer. Just pick the first one that answers your question and mark it "accepted"

Answer (score 1):

It's so because your request returns json object that has no field called `total_coins`, but it has field called `experience`, which type is object also. And that (`experience`) object has field called `total_coins`.

So you should:
1. Get object, stored as `experience` field's value.
2. Get `total_coins` field's value of received object.

To achieve this, use code, suggested by [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238468/json-decode-file-get-contents-problem/7238488#7238488) & [user900898](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238468/json-decode-file-get-contents-problem/7238494#7238494) (`$example = $obj->experience->total_coins`).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want
$example = $obj->experience->total_coins;